# Внутренний FrameLayout

Tags: android, framelayout

Решил добавить в приложение поверх `WebView` пустой `LinearLayout`. С помощью `FrameLayout`, конечно. При активации ночного режима в настройках, этот самый `LinearLayout` меняет свой background на прозрачно-черный *#BB000000*.
Все отлично работает, но столкнулся с проблемой. Хотелось бы, чтобы при включенном ночном режиме, под "черной пленкой" выезжал `DrawerLayout`.

То есть, нужен `FrameLayout` во `FrameLayout`?

Вот мой код main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/refresher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivty">

     <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wv"/>

  </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ll_bg">

    </LinearLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="3sp"
        android:paddingRight="3sp"
        android:listSelector="#C2C2C2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Я так понял, что во FrameLayout, включающий в себя WebView и LinearLayout нужно добавить FrameLayout с DrawerLayout. Может, обернуть весь мой код во FrameLayout?

Comment: несколько трудно понять, чего именно вы хотите? Чтобы ваш "*затемнитель*" накладывался так же и на Drawer?

Comment: @metalurgus, здравствуйте. Да, нужно, чтобы "затемнитель" закрывал и DrawerLayout тоже. А то, ослепнуть можно от внезапно светлого обьекта

Comment: Вы можете, например, накладывать затемнитель на основной экран, и затемнитель на ваш Drawer. Просто показывать их по одному и тому же событию. А можете получить корневой View вашего прилодение, я в него добавить затемнитель, который будет показываться поверх всего приложения

Comment: Стоит воздержаться от призывов к дискуссиям и обсуждениям, здесь не форум для мозговых штурмов. По вопросу: Я считаю,  что все эти затемнители - ересь, функционал, чуть более, чем полностью ненужный. Кому надо - убавит яркость на устройстве. Во первых - идет высаживание аккумулятора на высокой яркости, когда эта яркость не нужна, во вторых - прочие программы будут по прежнему слепить, никто не пользуется только одной программой в темноте.

Comment: @pavlofff, я с вами несогласен, мне часто бывает слишком много минимальной яркости, и я даже ставил себе когда-то приложение, которое на уровне системы добавляет затемнитель.

Comment: @metalargus, спасибо) теперь затемнитель закрывает весь контент.